# Querying S3 using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a setup with Kinesis Firehose ingesting data, AWS Lambda performing data transformation and dropping the incoming data into an S3 bucket. The S3 structure is organized by year/month/day/hour/messages.json, so all of the actual json files I am querying are at the 'hour' level with all year, month, day directories only containing sub directories.

My problem is I need to run a query to get all data for a given day. Is there an easy way to query at the 'day' directory level and return all files in its sub directories without having to run a query for 2020/06/15/00, 2020/06/15/01, 2020/06/15/02...2020/06/15/23?

I can successfully query the hour level directories since I can create a table and define the column name and type represented in my .json file, but I am not sure how to create a table in Athena (if possible) to represent a day directory with sub directories instead of actual files.

Answer (score 8):

To query only the data for a day without making Athena read all the data for all days you need to create a [partitioned table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) (look at the second example). Partitioned tables are like regular tables, but they contain additional metadata that describes where the data for a particular combination of the partition keys is located. When you run a query and specify criteria for the partition keys Athena can figure out which locations to read and which to skip.

How to configure the partition keys for a table depends on the way the data is partitioned. In your case the partitioning is by time, and the timestamp has hourly granularity. You can choose a number of different ways to encode this partitioning in a table, which one is the best depends on what kinds of queries you are going to run. You say you want to query by day, which makes sense, and will work great in this case.

There are two ways to set this up, the traditional, and the new way. The new way uses a feature that was released just a couple of days ago and if you try to find more examples of it you may not find many, so I'm going to show you the traditional too.

#### Using Partition Projection

Use the following SQL to create your table (you have to fill in the columns yourself, since you say you've successfully created a table already just use the columns from that table – also fix the S3 locations):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cszlos_firehose_data (
  -- fill in your columns here
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `date` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "projection.enabled" = "true",
  "projection.date.type" = "date",
  "projection.date.range" = "2020/06/01,NOW",
  "projection.date.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd",
  "projection.date.interval" = "1",
  "projection.date.interval.unit" = "DAYS",
  "storage.location.template" = "s3://cszlos-data/is/here/${date}"
)
```

This creates a table partitioned by `date` (please note that you need to quote this in queries, e.g. `SELECT * FROM cszlos_firehose_data WHERE "date" = …`, since it's a reserved word, if you want to avoid having to quote it use another name, `dt` seems popular, also note that it's escaped with backticks in DDL and with double quotes in DML statements). When you query this table and specify a criteria for `date`, e.g. `… WHERE "date" = '2020/06/05'`, Athena will read only the data for the specified date.

The table uses [Partition Projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html), which is a new feature where you put properties in the `TBLPROPERTIES` section that tell Athena about your partition keys and how to find the data – here I'm telling Athena to assume that there exists data on S3 from 2020-06-01 up until the time the query runs (adjust the start date necessary), which means that if you specify a date before that time, or after "now" Athena will know that there is no such data and not even try to read anything for those days. The `storage.location.template` property tells Athena where to find the data for a specific date. If your query specifies a range of dates, e.g. `… WHERE "date" > '2020/06/05'`. Athena will generate each date (controlled by the `projection.date.interval` property and formatted by the `projection.date.format` format) and read data in `s3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/06`, `s3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/07`, etc.

You can find a full [Kinesis Data Firehose example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-kinesis-firehose-example.html). It shows how to use the full hourly granularity of the partitioning, but you don't want that so stick to the example above.

#### The traditional way

The traditional way is similar to the above, but you have to add partitions manually for Athena to find them. Start by creating the table using the following SQL (again, add the columns from your previous experiments, and fix the S3 locations):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cszlos_firehose_data (
  -- fill in your columns here
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `date` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/'
```

This is exactly the same SQL as above, but without the table properties. If you try to run a query against this table now you will not get any results. The reason is that you need to tell Athena about the partitions of a partitioned table before it knows where to look for data (partitioned tables must have a `LOCATION`, but it really doesn't mean the same thing as for regular tables).

You can add partitions in many different ways, but the most straight forward for interactive use is to use [`ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html). You can add multiple partitions in one statement, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE cszlos_firehose_data ADD
PARTITION (`date` =  '2020-06-06') LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/06'
PARTITION (`date` =  '2020-06-07') LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/07'
PARTITION (`date` =  '2020-06-08') LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/08'
PARTITION (`date` =  '2020-06-09') LOCATION 's3://cszlos-data/is/here/2020/06/09'
```

If you start reading more about partitioned tables you will probably also run across the `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` statement as a way to load partitions. This command is unfortunately really slow, and it only works for Hive style partitioned data (e.g. `…/year=2020/month=06/day=07/file.json`) – so you can't use it.