# Athena Partition - partition by any month and day

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, ddl, amazon-athena

I've read [Partitioning data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) in Athena for query Amazon s3,

I want to create one table with yearly data and to be able to partitioned it by any month and day.

So in the end I would be able to query between desired dates from all the year as below:

```
Select ...
from ...
where date between between '2015-03-01' and '2015-06-31'
```

Where 'date' is the partition s3 folders.

I didn't find a way to partitioned date for month and day, meaning to partition the folders under 'year' folder.

Only succussed to partitioned specific dates as [doc suggest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html):

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD
  PARTITION (dt = '2014-04-21') LOCATION 's3://.../2014/04/21/'
  PARTITION (dt = '2016-05-15') LOCATION 's3://.../2016/05/15/'
```

I have data in the structure:

```
s3://.../2014/04/21/file.csv
```

I'm using the partition with Alter Table method as doc suggest.

Could you tell me if there's a good way to do what I need?

Comment: Someone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you still searching for an answer?

By default, Athena expects your folder structure to be in key=value format, for example, `/year=2022/month=04/day=22` etc. If your paths don't have the key names, you need to:

a) specify a path pattern using parameter `storage.location.template` (in your case, it will be for example `s3://..../${year}/${month}/${day}`).

b) define the rules of partition projection (so you don't have to specify a partition for each day manually) and partition keys. You need to refer to the values specified in the template in the previous point.

It's described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html.

Comment: I was struggling with the same issue last week, so I know your pain. It was also described in that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575827/querying-s3-using-athena (see the answer, section: "Using Partition Projection"). And oh, partitions defined this way won't be visible in Glue catalog.